# How do I make a fixed footer for an entire application?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am making a music app that has SlidingTab layout with viewpager. I have included a footer at the bottom of the main activity layout (just like Google play music). Now each of those viewpager fragments contain lists or grids. On clicking each grid/list item (say music album/genre/artist etc) it starts a new activity that displays the details of the grid item(number of songs etc). But I want this new activity to be placed above the footer and I don't want to include a footer in each activity.

Should I replace activity with fragment, if yes, how?

Please see this image to get an idea of what I intent to do
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgL0u.png

My question is should the green section screen be a fragment? If yes, how do I launch it?

Comment: You can add a static footer in the activity layout. and switcher views could be fragments. So fragments will keep on sliding and footer would be persistent.

Answer (score 0):

Based on you requirements, You can add a static footer in the activity layout. Switcher view in your Viewpager could be different fragments.

So fragments would keep on changing and footer would be persistent. There are many tutorials available out there related with using fragments with activities.

[One could be found here.](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html)   [Also have a look at this one](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html).

**Update[as per the image updated in the question]:** There could be many ways to achieve the UI you mentioned. Currently i could think of these ways:

1. You can have Base Activity class that will be extended by all the activities. In that base class you could add the code for dynamically adding footer at the bottom. In this approach you will have to take care of providing margins at the bottom of all your activity layouts.
2. Another approach could be designing `footer.xml` and including it all you layout files using `<include/>` tag
3. Or alternatively you can create a Singleton class that would inflate `footer.xml`. This singleton instance can be used to display persistent footer

Comment: That's fine. I have no problem with the viewpager. The problem arises when I start a new activity (by clicking on a grid item). Please see the image I have added

Comment: I want exactly the same footer throughout out the application.

Comment: Currently I am using include tag, but that doesn't really do the job. I want same footer, not a copy of it in every activity. Thats why I asked if it can be done using fragments. Should the green part in my 2nd image be a fragment instead of an activity?

Comment: Yes that could be fragment.

Comment: How? Please write some code..something bit more elaborate.

Comment: What exactly do I do with the singleton class? Suppose I create a class that extends application and in that class I inflate the footer using the singleton. Will it persist through all activities? AS in, will all activities be created "above" the footer?

Answer (score 0):

footer should be fragment. put it in your xml layout activities by fragment tag. in onCreateView() update your views, check if media is playing and so on ...
this way you have a single class to take care of and there is no duplicity.
also initializing views as static variables might help

hope this helps:

```
public class PlayFragment extends Fragment implements MyStaticStreamAudio.OnCompleteListener {

static boolean isPlaying = false;
static ToggleButton play;
static Button next, back;
static TextView titleView;


public PlayFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_play, container, false);

    play = (ToggleButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tbPlay);
    next = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.bNext);
    back = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.bBack);
    titleView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);

    if (isPlaying) {
        play.setEnabled(true);
        play.setChecked(true);
    }

    play.setOnClickListener(new PlayChangeListener());
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (canNext()) {
                goNext();
                updateView();
            }
        }
    });
    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (canBack()) {
                goBack();
                updateView();
            }
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}

private void goBack() {
MyStaticStreamAudio.goBack();
    resetAndPlay();
}

private void goNext() {
MyStaticStreamAudio.goNext();
    resetAndPlay();

}

public void pauseMode() {
    isPlaying = false;
    play.setChecked(false);
    play.setEnabled(true);
}

private void resetAndPlay() {
    MyStaticStreamAudio.reset();
    MyStaticStreamAudio.initializePlayer(getActivity());
    MyStaticStreamAudio.play();
}

boolean canNext() {
    int current = MyStaticStreamAudio.getCurrentTrack();
    return current < MyStaticStreamAudio.getTracks();
}

boolean canBack() {
    int current = MyStaticStreamAudio.getCurrentTrack();
    return current > 1;
}


public void updateView() {

    if (canNext())
        next.setEnabled(true);
    else
        next.setEnabled(false);
    if (canBack())
        back.setEnabled(true);
    else
        back.setEnabled(false);

    if (play != null) {
        play.setEnabled(false);
        play.setChecked(true);
    }
}

public void startStream() {
    isPlaying = true;
    updateView();
}


@Override
public void onComplete() {
    play.setChecked(false);
    progress.setIndeterminate(false);
}

public void playMode() {
    play.setEnabled(true);
    play.setChecked(true);
}
```

}

Comment: Suppose I create a class that extends application and in that class I inflate the footer. Will it persist through all activities? AS in, will all activities be created "above" the footer?

Comment: I don't think extending application would help. you need multiple instances of one fragment class at same time. every fragment loads one layout and initialize it's views based on MediaPlayer object
check new update